# git force refresh of all files, including unmodified

Tags: git

Does someone know of a better way to re-checkout all files in the working directory than the following?
In other words, I want to force overwrite every file in the working directory, with the cached copy of a certain commit ref, regardless of whether or not the files have been modified.

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
rm -rf *
git checkout <ref> .
```

This works, but deletes untracked files, and doesn't delete hidden `.files`. Of course, I don't want to delete `.git`, but I do want other `.files` to be affected.
I could come up with a more complete way to delete all the files in the working directory, but a solution that stays within Git would be ideal.

Why I want to do this: changing AutoCRLF
Files have not been modified, but need to be rewritten from the cache.
The ref I'm using is simply HEAD, so `git checkout .`, but I wanted to generalize the question to any commit or branch.

#### Edit

For this problem, let's assume that the working directory is clean (unmodified).
If you have changes, you can always `git stash` before doing this.

Comment: Git is going to make this difficult for you, since it doesn't want you to lose unsaved work. Does git stash followed by git checkout work for you?

Comment: No, `git stash` doesn't affect unmodified files. Let's assume no files are modified. OP edited to clarify this.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17223639/8362098) on Stack Overflow might help. The author suggests to simply checkout HEAD^1 and then the master again. This worked for me to update the working dir after changing autoCRLF.